# how can i set Enabled false after one click on my card view here using shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-cardview

Have implemented shared preferences in my app where after the cardview is clicked it should not be able to be clicked again  have done the part of maintaining the color of the cardview and text color but unfortunately  you can still click the cardview , i want to be also disabled using shared preferences after it has been clicked.
*In other words after one click disable the clicks and save that state using shared preferences, want to avoid multiple clicks*

**Here is my code**

```
        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (getContext ());
        mEditor = mPreferences.edit ();

        checkSharedPreferences ();

        //save the cardview preference

        if(cardView.isEnabled ())
        {
            //set a cardview state
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.cardviewsnal),"true");
            //disabling the button after one click

            mEditor.commit ();

            //save the color of the cardview
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.colorCardview),"#2b43f");
            mEditor.commit ();

            //save the textcolor pf the cardview
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.textcolorsnal),"#ffffff");
            mEditor.commit ();
        } else
        {
            //set a cardview state
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.cardviewsnal),"false");
            //disabling the button after one click
            cardView.setEnabled (false);
            mEditor.commit ();

            //save the color of the cardview
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.colorCardview),"#ffffff");
            mEditor.commit ();

            //save the textcolor pf the cardview
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.textcolorsnal),"#2b434f");
            mEditor.commit ();

        }






       //setting the click listener to send the request to specific section api anf return response

       cardView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(cardView.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor () ==-1 || textView.getTextColors ().getDefaultColor () ==-1)
               {
                   //change background color
                   cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));
                   textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
                   Toast.makeText (getActivity (),"Request Sent to SNAL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                   cardView.setEnabled (false);




               }
               else {

                   cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
                   textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));




               }

           }
       });
 /**
     * *Check the shared preferences and set them accordingly
     */
    private void checkSharedPreferences()
{
    String cardviewsnal = mPreferences.getString (getString (R.string.cardviewsnal),"false");
    String colorCardview = mPreferences.getString (getString (R.string.colorCardview),"#ffffff");
    String textcolorsnal = mPreferences.getString (getString (R.string.textcolorsnal),"#2b434f");

    if(cardviewsnal.equals ("false")){
        cardView.setEnabled (true);
    }
    else
    {
        cardView.setEnabled (true);
    }

    if(colorCardview.equals ("#ffffff"))
    {
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
    }
    else
    {
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));
    }

    if(textcolorsnal.equals ("#2b434f"))
    {
        textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));
    }
    else {
        textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply edit the onClick method in your onClickListener:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(cardView.isEnabled()) {
        cardView.setEnabled(false); 
        // do other things like writing to SharedPreferences and changing bg colors.
    } else {
        // set background colors 
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
        textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));
    }
}
```

I assume that would work. Also, don't you mean to set the cardView disabled if it has been read from memory in your checkPreferences method?

```
if(cardviewsnal.equals ("false")){
    cardView.setEnabled (false); // was cardView.setEnabled(true) in your code
}
```